# How to integrate facebook (Share and Login) functionality in Android Native Application?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

It is posible for do this(.How to integrate facebook (Share and Login) functionality in Android Native Application?)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is possible using Facebook [SDK for android](https://developers.facebook.com/android/). Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search give me this result https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/

hope this helps. :)

Thanks

Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

in this site

https://developers.facebook.com/android/

you will find necessary samples and tutorials..